# Poisson-like distribution but with varying success rate at each step, closed form?

Tags: probability, recreational-mathematics

I'm doing a personal math question based on the game Gloomhaven.  In it, bosses have a deck of 8 cards.  Abstracting down to the information needed for the math,   4 cards are "hits",  2 cards are "hits, then reshuffle the discard and deck back to 8 cards",  and 2 cards are "misses".  I'm investigating the percentages of at least $n$ hits in a row.

Starting from a state of a full deck, I've solved the problem using recursion. Let $p(n)$ be the probability of getting at least $n$ hits in a row from a full deck.  Let $f(n)$ be the amount of times one can draw pure hits (no reshuffles) in a row.

Then breaking things down into when does the first hit and reshuffle happen, we get  $$f(1)=\frac 4 8, f(2)=\frac 3 7 \cdot f(1), f(3)=\frac 2 6f(2), f(4)=\frac 15 f(3), f(5)=0$$
$$p(1)=\frac 6 8$$ $$p(2)=f(2)+f(1)\frac 2 7 + \frac 2 6 p(1)$$

$$p(3)=f(3)+f(2)\frac 2 6+f(1)\frac 2 7p(1)+\frac 2 8 p(2)$$
$$p(4)=f(4)+f(3)\frac 2 5+f(2)\frac 2 6p(1)+f(1)\frac 2 7 p(2)+\frac 2 8 p(3)$$
$$p(5)=f(4)\frac 2 4+f(3)\frac 2 5 p(1)+f(2)\frac 2 6p(2)+f(1)\frac 2 7 p(3)+\frac 2 8 p(4)$$
$$p(6)=f(4)\frac 2 4 p(1)+f(3)\frac 2 5 p(2)+f(2)\frac 2 6p(3)+f(1)\frac 2 7 p(4)+\frac 2 8 p(5)$$

$$p(n)=f(4)\frac 2 4 p(n-5)+f(3)\frac 2 5 p(n-4)+f(2)\frac 2 6p(n-3)+f(1)\frac 2 7 p(n-2)+\frac 2 8 p(n-1)$$
for $n>6$. To condense it down to a singular summation form with recursion,  define $f(0)=1$ then we get
$$p(n)=\sum_ {i=0}^4 \frac 2 {4+i}f(i)p(n-i-1)$$
I'm sure I could probably come up with notation/conventions for $p(0)$ through $p(-4)$ to fold in the earlier cases, not a priority.

I say it's poisson-like because it is counting "at least n hits in a row$ and the probability isn't fixed but shifts at each step.  I put it all in to excel and got good working numbers.

My open questions:
(1) Is there any way to do this in a closed form without using recursion?
(2) Is there any way to calculate an expected value?  I suppose I'd have to modify it from "at least $n$" to "exactly $n$" by throwing a miss at the end, but even so I have no idea how to do countably infinite sum with a recursive formula...

Comment: I dont understand what the following mean "then reshuffle the discard and deck back to 8 cards"

Comment: It meant replace all the cards drawn and shuffle.   Basically it's draw without replacement, unless one of those 2 cards are hit, in which case it resets to 8 @Masacroso

Comment: sorry but the gameplay is not very clear. Let me see if I understand it: the boss draw a card and play it. If it is a hit then it hits you and the card is discarded in a pile and the round finish, if it is an "hit and reshuffle" then it hits you and after it get all eight cards, played or not, reshuffle it and put as a deck for the next round. Its something like this?

Comment: @Masacroso yes.

Comment: but then, what is "a row"? Just drawing a card?

Comment: "a row" means that the streak of hits is not interrupted by a miss

Comment: I understand. However something is wrong in your calculus, as $p(1)=\frac{4}{8}\cdot \frac{2}{7}+\frac{2}{8}\cdot \frac{2}{8}$, as you want to consider only one hit, so in the next draw you need to get a miss, and there is two ways to get only a hit: getting a hit and after a miss, or getting a hit&reshuffle and after a miss

Comment: As I said, this math was for "at least n" hits in a row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your first question, sure you knows that the recursion is linear, so it have a closed form. However I dont see a way to have a closed form without the recursion, and if it exists I dont think it will be simpler as solving the linear recursion.

For your second question, the expectation, we can compute it easily from the recursion. If $X$ count the number of hits in a row, then

$$
\mu:=\operatorname{E}[X]=\sum_{k\geqslant 1}k \Pr [X=k]=\sum_{k\geqslant 1}\Pr [X\geqslant k]
$$

Then, using your notation, we have that

$$
\mu=\sum_{n\geqslant 1}p(n)=\sum_{k=1}^5 c_k \sum_{n\geqslant 1}p(n-k)=\sum_{k=1}^5 c_k (k+\mu),\quad c_k:=\frac{2}{3+k}f(k-1)\\
\therefore\quad \mu=\frac{\sum_{k=1}^5 k\,c_k}{1-\sum_{k=1}^5 c_k}
$$